# Rmarkdown beamer: How to left justify the title page

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, beamer

How is it possible to align the title page of my Rmarkdown beamer presentation to the LEFT instead of the default center?

Example , default is center:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "S SS"
date: "2/4/2018"
output: beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.
````

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can switch to a left aligned title page by using

```
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][left]
```

To use this in rmarkdown, place this line in a file called `preamble.tex` and use

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "S SS"
date: "2/4/2018"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    includes:
      in_header: preamble.tex

---

test
```

[image]

---

*Edit:*

with an up-to-date version of markdown, you can also directly do

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "S SS"
date: "2/4/2018"
output: 
  beamer_presentation
header-includes:
  - \setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][left]
---

test
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack until someone comes along with a better answer: We'll dispense with a standard beamer title slide and just format the first slide as if it were a title slide:

````
---
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{color}
---

\color{blue}
\LARGE{\textbf{This is the title}}  
\color{black}
\vspace{0.2cm}
\large{Author Name}  
\large{February 4, 2018}

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown presentation. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document.
````

[image]